# Require a local file on client device using PHP

Tags: php, security, include, controls, require

I have a web site that should be accessed only through specific devices, I was thinking of adding some code that would only allow the website to run on specific machine or else will direct the user to another website.

I was thinking of something like require() where I would require a file that I would set myself on specific location.

I am thinking of something like this:

```
<?php
require ("c:\key.php");
?>
```

The website is online on an Apache server, and I am looking for some code that if the file is not found the user gets an error or be directed.

If the way I am thinking is not right please guide me to what shall I do.

Appreciate all efforts.

Comment: *"I am looking for some code that if the file is not found the user gets an error or be directed"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php and then use a header.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The PHP code does never reach the client, only the output does. PHP is purely a serversided language (in case of a webserver) and therefor can not include files on the visitor's computer (if the file is accessible through public methods like HTTP it is, obviously).

If you want something like this to work, you would have to send a POST / GET request containing the file you want to use to 'authenticate', however, I think this would be a really stupid thing to do.

If you only want it to be accessed through specific devices, what kind of 'specific' are we talking about? If you only want mobile devices, there are other methods to do so, such as media queries (this way you don't have to redirect to view a mobile website) or checking the useragent.

If this is a matter of authentication, use cookies to identify who is using your website (however these can be stolen) or give people a password to authenticate.